# JavaScript setTimeout() issue in android webview when date is changed

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an application based on `android webview` , and `HTML page` , `JavaScript` which pulls result from `Android` end.

I have a simple method in JavaScript for pulling :

```
function GetData()
{
   var msg = Result.GetResult(); // Method on android end
   alert("Result :" + msg);
   setTimeout(GetData,5000);
}
```

This method will execute after every 5 seconds , and fetch results. This works fine as long as I don't change the date.

When I change the date to any previous date , `setTimeout` starts triggering in `milliseconds`. Same case happens with `setInterval()`.

And also it works fine on the webview on `Android KitKat` , whether I change date or not.

Comment: Do you mean you're changing the Android system time (date)? And FYI Kitkat runs a new javascript/rendering engine called Chromium.

Comment: Yes , I am changing Android system date.

Comment: Yes I know this. Just want to know whether there is any workaround ?

Comment: Actually this looks like a stackoverflow waiting to happen because it's going to call itself indefinitely. You should wrap the function in a setInterval method and remove the setTimeout which calls itself. See "anonymous functions" here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: I applied your solution , when I change the date , setInterval() is triggered only once.

Comment: You could stop the timer on onPause and reinitalise it on onResume. Your application would be in the background when they change the time and it would not affect your JS.